# Possible steps to improve SQL Server query performance

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a search procedure that is being passed around 15-20 (optional) parameters and the search procedure calls their respective functions to check if the value passed in parameter exists in the database. So, it is basically a `Search` structure based on a number of parameters.

Now, since the database is going to have millions of records, I expect the simple plain search procedure to fail right away. What are the ways that can improve query performance?

What I have tried so far:

1. Clustered index on `FirstName` column  of database (as I expect it to be used very frequently)
2. `Non Clustered index` on rest of the columns that are basis of the user search and also the `include` keyword.

**Note:**

I am looking for more ways to optimize my queries.

Most of the queries are nothing but select statements checked against a condition.

One of the queries uses `GroupBy` clause.

I have also created a `temporary table` in which I am inserting all the matched entries.

Comment: The clustered index should be on a column that's unique, narrow, static and if possible ever-increasing. A column called `FirstName` to me is none of that - most likely not unique, most likely not narrow (not just 4 bytes or so), maybe static, but could change.... this seems like a **horribly bad choice** for a clustered index! The clustered index is the most important index in your table and has effects on all nonclustered indexes as well - choose it wisely!

Comment: @marc_s: That helped. I would have never though of it that way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First  `Run` the `query` from `Sql Server Management Studio` and look at the query plan to see where the bottle neck is. Any place you see a "table scan" or "index scan" it has to go through all data to find what it is looking for. If you create appropriate indexes that can be used for these operations it should increase performance.

***Below Listed are some tips for improving the performance of sql query..***

**Avoid Multiple Joins in a Single Query**

Try to avoid writing a SQL query using multiple joins that includes outer joins, cross apply, outer apply and other complex sub queries. It reduces the choices for Optimizer to decide the join order and join type. Sometime, Optimizer is forced to use nested loop joins, irrespective of the performance consequences for queries with excessively complex cross apply or sub queries.

**Eliminate Cursors from the Query**
Try to remove cursors from the query and use set-based query; set-based query is more efficient than cursor-based. If there is a need to use cursor than avoid dynamic cursors as it tends to limit the choice of plans available to the query optimizer. For example, dynamic cursor limits the optimizer to using nested loop joins.

**Avoid Use of Non-correlated Scalar Sub Query**
You can re-write your query to remove non-correlated scalar sub query as a separate query instead of part of the main query and store the output in a variable, which can be referred to in the main query or later part of the batch. This will give better options to Optimizer, which may help to return accurate cardinality estimates along with a better plan.

**Avoid Multi-statement Table Valued Functions (TVFs)**
Multi-statement TVFs are more costly than inline TFVs. SQL Server expands inline TFVs into the main query like it expands views but evaluates multi-statement TVFs in a separate context from the main query and materializes the results of multi-statement into temporary work tables. The separate context and work table make multi-statement TVFs costly.

**Create a Highly Selective Index**
Selectivity define the percentage of qualifying rows in the table (qualifying number of rows/total number of rows). If the ratio of the qualifying number of rows to the total number of rows is low, the index is highly selective and is most useful. A non-clustered index is most useful if the ratio is around 5% or less, which means if the index can eliminate 95% of the rows from consideration. If index is returning more than 5% of the rows in a table, it probably will not be used; either a different index will be chosen or created or the table will be scanned.

**Position a Column in an Index**
Order or position of a column in an index also plays a vital role to improve SQL query performance. An index can help to improve the SQL query performance if the criteria of the query matches the columns that are left most in the index key. As a best practice, most selective columns should be placed leftmost in the key of a non-clustered index.

Drop Unused Indexes
Dropping unused indexes can help to speed up data modifications without affecting data retrieval. Also, you need to define a strategy for batch processes that run infrequently and use certain indexes. In such cases, creating indexes in advance of batch processes and then dropping them when the batch processes are done helps to reduce the overhead on the database.

**Statistic Creation and Updates**
You need to take care of statistic creation and regular updates for computed columns and multi-columns referred in the query; the query optimizer uses information about the distribution of values in one or more columns of a table statistics to estimate the cardinality, or number of rows, in the query result. These cardinality estimates enable the query optimizer to create a high-quality query plan.

**Revisit Your Schema Definitions**
Last but not least, revisit your schema definitions; keep on eye out that appropriate FORIGEN KEY, NOT NULL and CEHCK constraints are in place or not. Availability of the right constraint on the right place always helps to improve the query performance, like FORIGEN KEY constraint helps to simplify joins by converting some outer or semi-joins to inner joins and CHECK constraint also helps a bit by removing unnecessary or redundant predicates.

[Reference](http://www.developer.com/db/10-ways-to-improve-sql-query-performance.html)

Comment: You might want to add the link http://www.developer.com/db/10-ways-to-improve-sql-query-performance.html.