# T-Sql Datatime Year Group by for too much data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

The response to this query returned 2 minutes...

```
SELECT YEAR(T1.SP_CreateDate) AS DATEYEAR, COUNT(1) AS TOTALCOUNT 
FROM LP_SocialPost T1 WHERE T1.SP_BO_ID = 67
GROUP BY YEAR(T1.SP_CreateDate)


DATEYEAR    TOTALCOUNT
---------|-------------
2015        452036
```

Total data count for LP_SocialPost table = 2.8M

How to reduce query time?

Thanx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible steps to improve SQL Server query performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187940/possible-steps-to-improve-sql-server-query-performance)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have index on your table create a `Non Clustered Index` on your table.

You can create index on `SP_BO_ID` column with covering `SP_CreateDate` column. This index will help you query to perform a `index seek` instead of table scan

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX indexname
  ON LP_SocialPost (SP_BO_ID)
  include (SP_CreateDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe... using an analytic...

depending on existing indexes.

```
SELECT YEAR(T1.SP_CreateDate) AS DATEYEAR, 
       COUNT(1) over (partition by Year(T1.SP_CreateDate)) AS TOTALCOUNT 
FROM LP_SocialPost T1 
WHERE T1.SP_BO_ID = 67
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx for more on analytics